# When launching the VMWARE console via VSphere most of the display is not displayed

Tags: virtual-machine, console, vsphere

When I launch a console via VSphere client I cannot see the entire display.

[image: screenshot]

How do I resolve? It's like you can only see 2/3 of the screen as the rest is blanked out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you have found an answer by now. If not, the easiest thing to do is to go into the properties and check "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings".

If that doesn't seem to work, run the program in compatibility mode for Windows 7.

[image]